# How to set up Twitter Bootstrap with Ruby Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, rbenv

Hi I have Ruby Rails set up on Mac OSX with Homebrew and Rbenv.

I now want to play around with Bootstrap incorporated into that setup but I'm not sure how to set Bootstrap up accordingly.

Has anyone got any advice / setup guides?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your Gemfile:
`gem 'bootstrap-sass'`
and then bin/rake bundle install

Answer (score 1):

The easiest thing is to use the twitter-bootstrap-rails gem https://github.com/seyhunak/twitter-bootstrap-rails

Answer (score 0):

Step-1:

You need to include the Bootstrap gem in your Gemfile which you can do just by adding the following line of code:

gem 'bootstrap-sass'

Visit the following link for more details on the bootstrap gem:
https://rubygems.org/gems/bootstrap-sass

Step-2:

Once you have added the gem to Gemfile, you just need to run the following command:

bundle install

Step-3:

Now, you are ready to import the bootstrap peoperties to your stylesheet. Just add the follwoing two @imports to your css/scss:

@import "bootstrap-sprockets";
@import "bootstrap";

Hope it works for you!

Comment: I'm pretty noob to Rails.  Just created a new rails app and then tried to run the command: gem 'bootstrap-sass'  and got the message:  Unknown command bootstrap-sass  Next I used:  gem install bootstrap and it now seems to be installed. After this it still didn't recognise the: gem 'bootstrap-sass'  Do I still need to do this part suggested?

Comment: @SJD. Yes, I would suggest you to follow the above three steps. For more details, you can visit:    https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap-sass